# Freeradius server is not accepting accounting packets through tcpreplay

Tags: linux, radius, freeradius, pcap, tcpreplay

I am running a free radius server on system A. I am sending test accounting requests using radclient `radclient -x systemA acct testing123` from system B. I can see that the radius server recieved these requests from its debug logs.

I had saved these accounting requests packets at system B using `tcpdump -i eth0 portrange 1812-1815 -w rad2.pcap -s 0` . Now, when i replay these pcaps using tcpreplay from system B, the radius server shows no sign of receiving these packets even though i can see that the packets have reached systemA.

Why isn't freeradius server not recieving these packets?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up FreeRadius to log all requests?  http://wiki.freeradius.org/config/Logging

I'm pretty sure it is just discarding the packets as replays, but if you haven't set it up to log verbosely, you probably will not see any indication of it discarding the packets.

Comment: or just run it with -X, could be that the packet contents if slig